# Microsoft Bot Framework V4: System.NullReferenceException: 'Unable to locate SkillConversationIdFactoryBase in HostContext'

Tags: c#, botframework

I am working on creating a workflow which allows composer created dialogs to be integrated into a bot skill project.

To accomplish this I am trying to follow the instructions in this post: https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/handbook/experimental-add-composer/

My composer created dialogs including calling a skill.  When I initiate that intent through the Bot Emulator I get this error:

`System.NullReferenceException: 'Unable to locate SkillConversationIdFactoryBase in HostContext'`

The setup to get to this error is time consuming so I have created a git repo which can be started fairly easily to demonstrate the issue.

The project can be found here:
https://github.com/silverbulletgt/Integrate-Composer-Dialog-Using-Skill

**To recreate the issue:**

**Prerequisites**

- Install Bot Emulator: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/master/README.md

**Step to Recreate the Issue**

1. Open the solution file in visual studio
   `Integrate-Composer-Dialog-Using-Skill.sln`
2. Put a breakpoint on `line 72` of `DefaultAdapter.cs` - this is where the error can be seen
3. Start debugging the project
4. Open Bot Emulator
5. Connect to the bot: http://localhost:3978/api/messages
6. Type `"Greeting"`
7. Bot should respond with `"Hello, I have recognized that you said greeting"` - This means that the composer dialog integration is working as expected.
8. Type `"Skill"`
9. The breakpoint on `line 72` of `DefaultAdapter.cs` should trigger giving details of the error.

Error & stack trace can be found here: https://github.com/silverbulletgt/Integrate-Composer-Dialog-Using-Skill/blob/master/Readme/error%20stack%20trace.txt

**Edit:**

I was able to compile the Bot Builder code [Bot Builder GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet) & connect it to my project so that I could debug.  I found the error to be happening on `line 157` of `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.BeginSkill.cs` code [BeginSkill.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive/Actions/BeginSkill.cs).

This line is trying to get the `SkillConversationFactoryBase` out of the `dialogContext.Context.TurnState`.  I'm investigating how I might add this so that it is populated when this code executes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/5057

Comment: Related question for .dialog setting value resolution issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363853/bot-framework-v4-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-uristring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fix: System.NullReferenceException: 'Unable to locate SkillConversationIdFactoryBase in HostContext' in Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.BeginSkill

This error was being caused by missing dependency injection requirements.
Added the below lines to Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<SkillConversationIdFactoryBase, SkillConversationIdFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(new HttpClient());
services.AddSingleton<BotFrameworkClient, BotFrameworkHttpClient>();
```

Added to DefaultAdapter.cs

New Field

```
private readonly SkillConversationIdFactoryBase _skillConversationIdFactoryBase;
```

New constructor parameters

```
SkillConversationIdFactoryBase skillConversationIdFactoryBase,
BotFrameworkClient botFrameworkClient
```

To the body of the constructor

```
_skillConversationIdFactoryBase = skillConversationIdFactoryBase;

Use(new RegisterClassMiddleware<SkillConversationIdFactoryBase>(_skillConversationIdFactoryBase));
Use(new RegisterClassMiddleware<BotFrameworkClient>(botFrameworkClient));
```

This fixed the initial exception however there was then a new exception when the skill was called.

Exception wasOperation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.d__10.MoveNext()

2. Fixing Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
   This exception was occurring because there was no endpiont api/skills.  I suppose that the Bot Composer adds this endpoint automatically somehow.

I added SkillController.cs based on the example here: [Bot Builder Tests JSON SkillController](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TestBot.Json/Controllers/SkillController.cs)

Then added dependency injection to support the controller.
Added to Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<ChannelServiceHandler, SkillHandler>();
            services.AddSingleton<BotAdapter>(sp => (BotFrameworkHttpAdapter)sp.GetService<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter>());
```

I tested a basic intent which does not use a skill to determine if there would be any conflict with the dependency injection impacting those.  The basic intent worked as expected though.

I updated the master branch with the changes [Project Repo](https://github.com/silverbulletgt/Integrate-Composer-Dialog-Using-Skill)